# Issue regarding 1-m relation

Tags: prisma

The current relation i have is that One user can only have 1 sublevel. And sublevel can have more users.

But when i try to create a sublevel ( without any reference at this time ) Lets say , i want to have a new sublevel where users can not be assigned just yet. It does not work.

Current Scheme:

```
model User {
  id             String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email          String    @unique
  password       String
  firstName      String
  lastName       String
  address        String
  postalCode     String
  city           String
  country        String
  email_verified Boolean
  subLevelId     String?
  sub            SubLevel? @relation(fields: [subLevelId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

}

model SubLevel {
  id           String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  sublevelName String
  sublevelCost Float
  users        User[]
}
```

The error i get is:

> > 3 export const createSubLevel = ({ input }) => { api | → 14   return db.subLevel.create({ api |          data: { api |
> > sublevelName: 'Cryptek-Standard', api |            sublevelCost: 0,
> > api |        +   user: { api |        +     create?:
> > UserCreateWithoutSubLevelInput |
> > UserUncheckedCreateWithoutSubLevelInput, api |        +
> > connectOrCreate?: UserCreateOrConnectWithoutSubLevelInput, api |
>
> - ```
>   connect?: UserWhereUniqueInput api |        +   }, api |        ?   id?: String api |          } api |        }) api |  api | Argument
>   ```
>
> user for data.user is missing. api |  api | Note: Lines with + are
> required, lines with ? are optional.

Is it not possible in prisma to do this ? I searched the docu but i can not seem to find the answer for it.

Comment: Could you also kindly provide the Prisma Query that leads to the error? (Maybe a simplified version, if necessary)

Comment: After further research i discovered i needed a 1-1 relationship. So ill mark this question as solved. Thanks for replying !

Comment: Oh alright, happy to hear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed into a 1-1 relationship